# Terminal on the web browser?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, terminal, webserver

Is there a way to put the terminal on the web browser instead, so I just fire up localhost:80 and then I'll have a terminal on it that I can use and whatever I execute it will execute on my local web server?

And the outputs I want to be displayed on the web browser too, just like a normal Terminal.

I'm using Ruby on Mac OS X/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [shellinabox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/), here are [deb packages](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/downloads/detail?name=shellinabox_2.10-1_i386.deb).

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages which allow you to log into a computer using ssh via a web browser, including [anyterm](http://anyterm.org/) and [AjaxTerm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/qweb/trac/wiki/AjaxTerm). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH).